# I want to declare and initialize this array outside the paint() function

Tags: java, paint, declaration, repaint

My program has 50 rectangle bars drawn on the screen. I initialize the bar objects using another class `Bar`. Everything works well, but I need a way to declare and initialize the bar objects in the main method.I have tried to declare and initialize in main method, but I am unable to pass parameters to the paint(Graphics g) method. How can I do this so my paint() function isn't doing all the work?

My current code:

```
import java.util.*;import java.awt.*;import javax.swing.*;import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends JFrame{

    public test(){
        setSize(1000,700);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void main(String args[]){
            repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Bar bar[] = new Bar[50];                  //declare object array
        int y = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++){             //initialize 50 bar objects
            bar[x] = new Bar(5,y,15,5);
            y += 6;       
        }    

        for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++){               //draw each bar object
           int height = bar[x].getHeight();
           int width = bar[x].getWidth();
           int locx = bar[x].getLocx();
           int locy = bar[x].getLocy();
           g.fillRect(locx,locy,width,height);             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn the array into an isntace variable, and do the initialization in the contructor.

Comment: is your main() supposed to be STATIC void main() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it as a class member

```
public class test extends JFrame{
  Bar bar[] = new Bar[50];
```

Set it in main

```
public void main(String args[]){
  bar[1] = new Bar();
}
```

Then access it in `paint()`

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
  bar[1].doSomething()
```

But you should run GUI calls on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) so as to avoid synchronization problems.  i.e. so that two separate things don't call a repaint.

Comment: Thanks, but do we use `static` when we declare the Bar array?

Comment: Depends how it's being accessed. Given the code you've provided, it makes little difference.